# How the order of $G/2G$ is $2^n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups

Let $G $ be an abelian group. In this section we shall use additive notation
for $G$, so the group operation will be denoted by ' $+$ ' the identity by $0$,
the inverse of $g$ by $-g$ and powers of $g$ by $2g, 3g, ....$

Let $2G$ be the subgroup of $G$ consisting of all elements of the form $g + g$ $(g \in  G)$. If $G$ has a basis of $n$ elements, then $G/2G$ is a group of order $2^n$.

How the order of $G/2G$ is  $2^n$? Plz show in an elementary way.

This an excerpt from "Algebraic number theory and Fermats last theorem by  Ian Stewart, David Tall (3rd ed.).

Comment: $G$ is a vector space over the field of two elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"... G has a basis of $n$ elements..." to me implies that $G$ is a *free* Abelian group of rank $n$, i.e. there is a basis made of $n$ *linearly independent* generators $g_1, g_2,\ldots,g_n\in G$; every element of $G$ can be uniquely represented as $m_1g_1+m_2g+\ldots+m_ng_n$ where $m_i\in\mathbb Z$ are "co-ordinates" in this basis.

(Recall we use the same terms in linear algebra, but the coefficients there come from a *field*, while here they come from the ring $\mathbb Z$ which is not a field. This makes calculations *slightly* more complicated.)

Now, note $2G$ is the subset of those elements of $G$ which have *even* co-ordinates, i.e. all $m_i$'s are even. That means that $G/2G$ is made up of "cosets" of the form $\lambda_1g_1+\ldots+\lambda_ng_n+2G$ where $\lambda_i\in\{0,1\}$. (Every $m_1g_1+\ldots+m_ng_n$ belongs to the coset $\lambda_1g_1+\ldots+\lambda_ng_n+2G$ where $\lambda_i =\text{ remainder in dividing }m_i\text{ by }2$). Thus, the number of those cosets (which is the order of $G/2G$) is $2^n$.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I agree that "basis" is not well-defined here, but perhaps it just means "generated by"?

Comment: Not a helpful for a beginner....... lost from 2nd line......

Comment: @JasonDeVito There will be obvious counterexamples. $G=\mathbb Z_3$ is also generated by one element but $2G=G$ and $G/2G$ would be trivial.

Comment: @Andrew Terribly sorry. I don't have the book at hand... - How do they define "basis" of an Abelian group? - they use that term, they must've defined it somewhere. Happy to rewrite the proof in more elementary ways, but need first to understand "what I am allowed to use".

Comment: Oh, good point about the counterexamples.

Comment: @Andrew Thanks, revised the answer, hope it suits you a bit better now.

Comment: Also, this is a nice trick to prove any two (finite) bases have the same cardinality, but you could just as well do what you do in linear algebra: make the transition matrices from one basis to another and vice versa. Those two matrices would be made up of integers, but you can just as well treat them as real matrices, see that they are inverse to each other, and conclude that they are both square matrices!